# Nonparametric bootstrap of one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness of fit test

Tags: bootstrap, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm fitting a Weibull distribution to some forestry data and I want to perform a test of whether or not there is sufficient evidence to indicate that the data does not come from a Weibull distribution. The modelling process involves finding a least-squares fit of the Weibull Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) to the Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function (ECDF), hence the parameters of the theoretical distribution are estimated from the data. I thought I'd apply a Nonparametric Bootstrapping procedure to the data set to look at the distribution of KS-test statistic values obtained, this is where I'm stuck.

I've implemented the procedure in 'R', but I've generated some test data to see what kind of answers I get when the data is generated from a Weibull distribution. The data is generated from the Weibull(5, 15) distribution and the output values are rounded to the nearest integer value, mostly so that they are reminiscent of my forestry data but partly because I understand that the nls() function demonstrates poor convergence on exact data. In each case the KS-test is then performed using the estimated CDF and the ECDF.

Integrating the model fitting and KS-test processes into a nonparametric bootstrapping procedure I would expect that the number of KS-test statistic values over the normal critical value of 0.136 (taken from http://www.cas.usf.edu/~cconnor/colima/Kolmogorov_Smirnov.htm using a sample size of 100) should give some indication of what proportion of KS-tests will exceed this value. My "results" indicate that:

1. There is a large variation in the results
2. Running a nonparametric bootstrapping procedure 50 times with 10,000 resamples takes a long time.
3. The proportion of interest, as a percentage, is between 2% and 60%.

The 'R' code is provided below, I'm interested to know if there's a problem with either my method, my implementation or my expectations.

```
## Bootstrapping on test data set.
library('boot')
require('minpack.lm')

## Set up parameters
sample.size <- 100
resamples <- 1000
no.tests <- 50

shape = 5
scale = 15

## generate data from weibull distribution
data.raw <- rweibull(sample.size, shape, scale)
data.raw <- round(data.raw)


## Weibull CDF for nonlinear regression fit
weibull.cdf <- function(x, shape, scale){
       1 - exp(-(x / scale)^shape)
}


## resampling function
boot.sample <- function(z, i){


       data.sum <- as.data.frame(table(z[i]))

       ## calculate ECDF
       cummulative.data <- c()

       for(k in 1:nrow(data.sum)){
              cummulative.data[k] <- sum(data.sum$Freq[1:k]) / sum(data.sum$Freq)
       }

       ## Create data frame
       data.sum <- cbind(data.sum, cummulative.data)
       data.sum <- as.data.frame(data.sum)
       names(data.sum) = c("class", "Freq", "Cumm")

       ## Define regression variables
       x <- data.sum$class
           x <- as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
           y <- data.sum$Cumm

       ## Perform nonlinear regression
       weibull.nls <- nlsLM(y ~ weibull.cdf(x, shape, scale), start = c(shape = 1,     scale = 10))

       ## Best-fit coefficients
       theta <- coef(weibull.nls)


       data.frame <- cbind(x,y)
       data.frame <- as.data.frame(data.frame)
       names(data.frame) = c("x", "y")

       p <- pweibull(x, shape = theta[1], scale = theta[2])
       model.frame <- cbind(x,p)
       model.frame <- as.data.frame(model.frame)
       names(model.frame) = c("x", "p")


       ## Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test Statistic
       weibull.ks <- ks.test(data.frame$y, model.frame$p)
       return(weibull.ks$statistic)

}

reject.ratio <- rep(0, no.tests)

for(j in 1:no.tests){
    weibull.boot <- boot(data.raw, boot.sample, R = resamples)

    CR <- weibull.boot$t

    reject.ratio[j] <- length(CR[CR > 0.136]) / resamples
}
```

Comment: I ran your code, and it gives a very tight range of outcomes - as it should, because 1000 bootstrap resamples should estimate the probability fairly well. But your whole setup is weird - it is quite unclear what you are trying to estimate.

Comment: Apologies @Aniko, I'll try being a bit more succinct. For a KS-test statistic value (K) I want to estimate, Pr(K > 0.136). In the code above the (poorly named) variable "reject.ratio" is the number of times I get K > 0.136, expressed as a proportion of the total number of resampling steps.

To see what kind of variation I get in my answer I repeat the whole process "n" times. So for example when I use set.seed(14293) the "reject.ratio" vector contains 10 estimates of the desired probability. What worries me is that there is a linear decrease in these values from 0.336 to 0.016 (in this case).

Comment: I ran your code with the seed you specified, and obtained a vector with 50 observations that range from 0.316 to 0.382. I have no idea why are you getting different results.